# how to configure the aws elastic beanstalk load balancer for different layers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

I read the `aws` documentation inside the elastic beanstalk program where `aws` is responsible for scaling the servers and auto managing it. In the same documentation there is an option for changing and configuring the load balancer. In my case I want to change it to balance the requests that come to the servers on the IP network layer (L3), but it says that only `HTTP` and `TCP` can be listened and balanced.

I am developing a chat application backend that need to be developed with scaling in considerations. how can I configure the load balancer to listen on `L3` ?

the chat application in order to work it must make the `tcp` connection with the server not the load balancer so that's why I must load the packets on the IP layer to the server so the server can establish a `tcp` connection with the app ( if I am wrong and I can do it on the `tcp` layer tell me ).

If I can't, does that give me another option or I will just be forced on using `ec2` and handle all the system management overhead myself and create my own load balancer ?

Answer (score 1):

ELB Classic operates at either Layer 4 or Layer 7.  Those are the options.

> the chat application in order to work it must make the tcp connection with the server not the load balancer so that's why I must load the packets on the IP layer to the server so the server can establish a tcp connection with the app.

You're actually incorrect about this.  If you need to know the client's source IP address, you can enable the Proxy Protocol on your ELB, and support this in your server code.

When the ELB establishes each new connection to the instance, with the Proxy Protocol enabled, the ELB emits a single line preamble containing the 5-way tuple describing the external connection, which your application can interpret.  Then it opens up the L4 connection's payload streams and is transparent for the remainder of the connection.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html

Comment: sorry if i don't get it .. what i know about the proxy is that it request data over the internet but modifies the source ip to act asif i am anonymous and when it recieves the request it sent it back to my real ip ... but i don't understand how it works or what it do in load balancers can you please tell me :D ?

Comment: You are thinking of a different kind of proxy.  This is about a feature in ELB called the *Proxy Protocol*, which is [an enhancement for layer 4 balancers, invented by load balancing pioneer Willy Tarreau](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) to solve exactly the problem that you have, with a layer 4 balancer.  It can be enabled in ELB so that you can identify the source of an external connection, behind the balancer -- exposing layer 3 information.  Please see the link here and the link in the answer above for an explanation of how it works, in detail.

Comment: ok  thats what i got from reading the links .. the proxy server at clients modifies the ipsource so the ELB uses the proxy protocol to get the real ip source right ? anyway just tell me if i make as you said and enabled  the proxy protocol , i can then create a scalable load baanced char servers ?